# How to print type of array items in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, go

When I try to unit test some code, I have some assertion like this:

```
expected := []interface{}{1}
actual := []interface{}{float64(1)}

if !reflect.DeepEqual(expected, actual); {
    t.Errorf("Expected <%T> %#v to equal <%T> %#v", actual, actual, expected, expected);
}
```

And got this output:

```
Expected <[]interface {}> []interface {}{1} to equal <[]interface {}> []interface {}{1}
```

How can I print this message to be more explicit?

Thanks!

[see this code in play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/JigknXTcdx)

Comment: Use `reflect.TypeOf` and call `Name()` on the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the types of the slices, not the types of the elements. And types of the slices are `[]interface{}`. That's why you see that.

If you want to see the dynamic types of the elements (their static type is always `interface{}`), then print the types of the elements:

```
fmt.Printf("Expected element type: %T, got: %T", expected[0], actual[0])
```

Which will output:

```
Expected element type: int, got: float64
```

**Note:**

The above code assumes you are comparing 2 slices with 1 element. If you don't want to check slice length and you want to handle slices with any length, you can use other verbs. For example you can use the `%t` verb which expects a `bool` value and wants to print `true` or `false`. Note that this is just an implementation decision and not guaranteed, but using `%t` for example will print all the slice elements; printing the respective `bool` value if it is of type `bool`, and will print the dynamic type and value of the element if the it is not of type `bool`.

Example:

```
data := []interface{}{1, float64(2), "3", time.Now()}
fmt.Printf("%t", data)
```

Output:

```
[%!t(int=1) %!t(float64=2) %!t(string=3)
    {%!t(int64=63393490800) %!t(int32=0) %!t(*time.Location=&{ [] [] 0 0 <nil>})}]
```

It's a bit ugly, but contains many useful info (e.g. types, values).